# Sharepoint 2010 alerts not working

Tags: email, alert

So the problem is I cant send email via alerts. So I far I ve checked this:
1) Alerts are activated in central administration for my application (activated and unlimeted)
2) User has permisions for the list (full control)
3) User has email
4) Emails are successfully sent via workflows and code
5) Alert subscription email is being successfully sent
6) Join group email is succesfully sent
7) ImmedSubscriptions table has all the data for notifications

I've checked the log file

```
AlertsJob loaded 10 of 10 event data records    7c0bd9fe-6c3f-4e23-8fec-e2e0f8312788
Verbose     AlertsJob loaded events with Ids between 749283, 749324 7c0bd9fe-6c3f-4e23-8fec-e2e0f8312788
Verbose     AlertsJob loaded 3 of 3 subscription records    7c0bd9fe-6c3f-4e23-8fec-e2e0f8312788
Verbose     AlertsJob, Filter for Immediate subscription with id {F298AE84-44EB-4689-B963-B0DE6FF45ABB} matched event with Id 749300    7c0bd9fe-6c3f-4e23-8fec-e2e0f8312788
Verbose     Alert for Immediate subscription {F298AE84-44EB-4689-B963-B0DE6FF45ABB}, event 749300, user CENTPART\test.user succeeded permissions check  7c0bd9fe-6c3f-4e23-8fec-e2e0f8312788
Verbose     AlertsJob, Filter for Immediate subscription with id {F298AE84-44EB-4689-B963-B0DE6FF45ABB} matched event with Id 749301    7c0bd9fe-6c3f-4e23-8fec-e2e0f8312788
Verbose     Alert for Immediate subscription {F298AE84-44EB-4689-B963-B0DE6FF45ABB}, event 749301, user CENTPART\test.user succeeded permissions check  7c0bd9fe-6c3f-4e23-8fec-e2e0f8312788
Verbose     AlertsJob, Filter for Immediate subscription with id {F298AE84-44EB-4689-B963-B0DE6FF45ABB} matched event with Id 749318    7c0bd9fe-6c3f-4e23-8fec-e2e0f8312788
Verbose     Alert for Immediate subscription {F298AE84-44EB-4689-B963-B0DE6FF45ABB}, event 749318, user CENTPART\test.user succeeded permissions check  7c0bd9fe-6c3f-4e23-8fec-e2e0f8312788
Verbose     AlertsJob, Filter for Immediate subscription with id {F298AE84-44EB-4689-B963-B0DE6FF45ABB} matched event with Id 749319    7c0bd9fe-6c3f-4e23-8fec-e2e0f8312788
Verbose     Alert for Immediate subscription {F298AE84-44EB-4689-B963-B0DE6FF45ABB}, event 749319, user CENTPART\test.user succeeded permissions check  7c0bd9fe-6c3f-4e23-8fec-e2e0f8312788
Verbose     AlertsJob, Filter for Immediate subscription with id {F298AE84-44EB-4689-B963-B0DE6FF45ABB} matched event with Id 749322    7c0bd9fe-6c3f-4e23-8fec-e2e0f8312788
Verbose     Alert for Immediate subscription {F298AE84-44EB-4689-B963-B0DE6FF45ABB}, event 749322, user CENTPART\test.user succeeded permissions check  7c0bd9fe-6c3f-4e23-8fec-e2e0f8312788
Verbose     AlertsJob, Filter for Immediate subscription with id {4808123B-CADE-4CA9-8CA6-4F5EA54C641C} matched event with Id 749300    7c0bd9fe-6c3f-4e23-8fec-e2e0f8312788
Verbose     Alert for Immediate subscription {4808123B-CADE-4CA9-8CA6-4F5EA54C641C}, event 749300, user CENTPART\test.user succeeded permissions check  7c0bd9fe-6c3f-4e23-8fec-e2e0f8312788
Verbose     AlertsJob, Filter for Immediate subscription with id {4808123B-CADE-4CA9-8CA6-4F5EA54C641C} matched event with Id 749301    7c0bd9fe-6c3f-4e23-8fec-e2e0f8312788
Verbose     Alert for Immediate subscription {4808123B-CADE-4CA9-8CA6-4F5EA54C641C}, event 749301, user CENTPART\test.user succeeded permissions check  7c0bd9fe-6c3f-4e23-8fec-e2e0f8312788
Verbose     AlertsJob, Filter for Immediate subscription with id {4808123B-CADE-4CA9-8CA6-4F5EA54C641C} matched event with Id 749318    7c0bd9fe-6c3f-4e23-8fec-e2e0f8312788
Verbose     Alert for Immediate subscription {4808123B-CADE-4CA9-8CA6-4F5EA54C641C}, event 749318, user CENTPART\test.user succeeded permissions check  7c0bd9fe-6c3f-4e23-8fec-e2e0f8312788
Verbose     AlertsJob, Filter for Immediate subscription with id {4808123B-CADE-4CA9-8CA6-4F5EA54C641C} matched event with Id 749319    7c0bd9fe-6c3f-4e23-8fec-e2e0f8312788
Verbose     Alert for Immediate subscription {4808123B-CADE-4CA9-8CA6-4F5EA54C641C}, event 749319, user CENTPART\test.user succeeded permissions check  7c0bd9fe-6c3f-4e23-8fec-e2e0f8312788
Verbose     AlertsJob, Filter for Immediate subscription with id {4808123B-CADE-4CA9-8CA6-4F5EA54C641C} matched event with Id 749322    7c0bd9fe-6c3f-4e23-8fec-e2e0f8312788
Verbose     Alert for Immediate subscription {4808123B-CADE-4CA9-8CA6-4F5EA54C641C}, event 749322, user CENTPART\test.user succeeded permissions check  7c0bd9fe-6c3f-4e23-8fec-e2e0f8312788
Verbose     Alertsjob results for immediate delivery: 13 prematches, 10 passed filtering, 10 of 10 passed security trimming, 8 final after rollup   7c0bd9fe-6c3f-4e23-8fec-e2e0f8312788
Verbose     Alertsjob results for scheduled delivery: 0 prematches, 0 passed filtering, 0 of 0 passed security trimming, 0 final after rollup   7c0bd9fe-6c3f-4e23-8fec-e2e0f8312788
Verbose     AlertsJob processed 8 immediate notifications in 8 digests, sent 0 emails, failed to send 0 emails  7c0bd9fe-6c3f-4e23-8fec-e2e0f8312788
```

So the log actualy says that i ve got subscriptions, there are some events to send, permission check succeeded.

But no emails were sent. How could this possbly happen?

Comment: Did you check junk mail folder or spam filters?  Did you check your mail server to see if the message is actually making it that far?

Comment: Checked spam - nothing. The message is not stuck on mail server (there is nothing there).

Comment: Its actually obvious that the problem is sharepoint related, because mail server is working fine.

Comment: Check your ULS log. I would run a ULS log viewer and then perform an action that should trigger the alert. This may shed some light on what's happening.

Comment: I ve posted an example of the log in the post. The weird part is job actualy has some notifications to send but doesnt send them (processed 8 immediate notifications in 8 digests, sent 0 emails, failed to send 0 emails)

Comment: Is 'Required checked out' option set to 'Yes' in the document library?

Comment: Normally you would troubleshoot alerts not sending [like this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_chen/archive/2009/11/20/alerts-in-sharepoint-troubleshooting-moss-wss.aspx) and [like this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13771.troubleshooting-steps-for-sharepoint-alert-email-does-not-go-out.aspx) there are some issues for alerts that come up based on product. What version are you using and do you have User Profile service enabled? (occasionally there are [user sync](http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_chen/archive/2010/10/13/troubleshooting-user-profile-sync-issues-on-sh